# Toggle class with expand/collapse all multiple accordions

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with a jquery script I am trying to write. It looks right to me but not quite there yet. Can someone please help me understand why this isn't working?

```
jQuery('.expand').click(function(){
    jQuery('.expandnav').find('div.menu-body').show('slow');

    if( ('.menu-body').is(':visible') ){
        (this).addClass('collapse-active');
    }else{
        (this).removeClass('collapse-active');
    }
});
```

When .expand is clicked .menu-body does show but the conditional doesn't seem to run. I have tested with alerts and no response...

i am using toggleClass on each individual accordion as there are many to the page but I need the addClass/removeClass to swap the +,- images. Hope that makes sense. Bottom line is the conditional is not responding.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `callback` method of `$.fn.show`, read more at http://api.jquery.com/show/

Here's a fiddle showing the proposed change: http://jsfiddle.net/pewt8/